# MonoTouch: How to set the "do not back up" attribute

Tags: ios5, xamarin.ios, nsfilemanager

I am trying to follow the following guidance from Apple about local file storage. How do I set the "do not back" attribute on files created by my apps in MonoTouch?

Technical docs here, but I can't find this in MonoTouch:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1719/_index.html

> Use the "do not back up" attribute for specifying files that should
>   remain on device, even in low storage situations. Use this attribute
>   with data that can be recreated but needs to persist even in low
>   storage situations for proper functioning of your app or because
>   customers expect it to be available during offline use. This attribute
>   works on marked files regardless of what directory they are in,
>   including the Documents directory. These files will not be purged and
>   will not be included in the user's iCloud or iTunes backup. Because
>   these files do use on-device storage space, your app is responsible
>   for monitoring and purging these files periodically."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is available since [MonoTouch 5.2](http://ios.xamarin.com/Releases/MonoTouch_5/MonoTouch_5.2) (and iOS 5.0.1) inside the `MonoTouch.Foundation.NSFileManager` type, methods [`SetSkipBackupAttribute`](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=M%3aMonoTouch.Foundation.NSFileManager.SetSkipBackupAttribute%28System.String,System.Boolean%29) and [`GetSkipBackupAttribute`](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=T%3aMonoTouch.Foundation.NSFileManager/M/GetSkipBackupAttribute).